# ROS2 listener not entering the callback function

Tags: ros, ros2, callback, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interfacing a ROS2 subscriber with a native RTI DDS publisher.

I have the following message structure for the message named `DetectedObjectList`

```
int16 id

//an array of objects of another message type

DetectedObject[ ] objects
```

and the DetectedObject.msg is defined as follows :

```
int16 id
 
int16 x

int16 y
```

I am publishing an `id` and an object of type `DetectedObject`

To Simplify the problem, now my msg file contains only int16 id.

If I look at the `RTI Admin Console`, the datatypes in the ROS2 listener and RTI are matched and everything seems to be ok.

I feel I am doing something wrong in the ROS2 listener node. Here is the snippet for my `ROS2 listener`

EDIT : Full ROS2 code.

```
import sys
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from openadx_msg.msg import (DetectedObjectList, DetectedObject)

class DemoNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('ros2_listener')
        self.sub = self.create_subscription(DetectedObjectList, 'vehicle/objects', self.object_callback)
    
    def object_callback(self,msg):
        print("entering callback")
        log = self.get_logger().info
        log('Received a message')
        log('id: {}.format(msg.id)')

def main(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args=sys.argv
    node=DemoNode()    // EDIT2
    rclpy.spin(node)

    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__=='__main__':  //EDIT3
    main()
```

Here is the code for the RTI DDS python connector :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ctypes import *
import sys
import os
from sys import path as sysPath
from os import path as osPath
from time import sleep
import math
filepath = osPath.dirname(osPath.realpath(__file__))
sysPath.append(filepath + "/../../../")
import rticonnextdds_connector as rti

def main():


    connector = rti.Connector("MyParticipantLibrary::Zero",
                          filepath + "/../ROS2_demo_nodes_py.xml")
    outputDDS = connector.getOutput("MyPublisher::VehicleObjectWriter")


    for i in range(1,50000):
            
            
            outputDDS.instance.setNumber("id_",i)
            outputDDS.write()

            toPrint = "id_ : " + repr(i)
            print(toPrint)
            

                    


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is the `xml` file used by this connector. The xml is a translated version of the ROS2 IDL file.

```
<dds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://community.rti.com/schema/5.1.0/rti_dds_profiles.xsd" version="5.1.0">

    <!-- Qos Library -->
    <qos_library name="QosLibrary">
        <qos_profile name="DefaultProfile" is_default_qos="true" base_name="BuiltinQosLib::Generic.510TransportCompatibility">
            <datawriter_qos>
                <property>
                    <value>
                        <element>
                        <name>dds.data_writer.history.memory_manager.fast_pool.pool_buffer_max_size</name>
                        <value>2147483647</value>
                        </element>
                    </value>
                </property>
            </datawriter_qos>
            
            <datareader_qos>
                <property>
                    <value>
                        <element>
                        <name>dds.data_writer.history.memory_manager.fast_pool.pool_buffer_max_size</name>
                        <value>2147483647</value>
                        </element>
                    </value>
                </property>
            </datareader_qos>
            <publisher_qos>
                <partition>
                    <name>
                        <element>rt/vehicle</element>
                    </name>
                </partition>
            </publisher_qos>
            <subscriber_qos>
                <partition>
                    <name>
                        <element>rt/vehicle</element>
                    </name>
                </partition>
            </subscriber_qos>
            <participant_qos>
                <transport_builtin>
                    <mask>UDPV4 | SHMEM</mask>
                </transport_builtin>
            </participant_qos>
        </qos_profile>
    </qos_library>

    <!-- types -->
    <types>
    <module name="openadx_msgs">
    <module name="msg">
    <module name="dds_">
      <const name="VehicleControl__GEAR_KEEP" type="int32" value="-1"/>
      <const name="VehicleControl__GEAR_PARK" type="int32" value="0"/>
      <const name="VehicleControl__GEAR_NEUTRAL" type="int32" value="1"/>
      <const name="VehicleControl__GEAR_DRIVE" type="int32" value="2"/>
      <const name="VehicleControl__GEAR_REVERSE" type="int32" value="3"/>
      <struct name= "VehicleControl_">
        <member name="accelerator_pedal_" type="float64"/>
        <member name="brake_pedal_" type="float64"/>
        <member name="steering_wheel_" type="float64"/>
        <member name="gear_" type="int32"/>
      </struct>
    </module>
    </module>
    </module>
    
    <module name="openadx_msgs">
    <module name="msg">
    <module name="dds_">
     <struct name= "DetectedObject_">
        <member name="id_" type="int32"/>
        <member name="x_" type="float32"/>
        <member name="y_" type="float32"/>
        <member name="v_rad_" type="float32"/>
        <member name="a_rad_" type="float32"/>
      </struct>
    </module>
    </module>
    </module>
    
       
    <module name="openadx_msgs">
    <module name="msg">
    <module name="dds_">
      <struct name= "DetectedObjectList_">
        <!--member name="header_" type="nonBasic"  nonBasicTypeName= "std_msgs::msg::dds_::Header_"/-->
        <member name="id_" type="int16"/>
        <!--member name="objects_" sequenceMaxLength="2147483647" type="nonBasic"  nonBasicTypeName= "openadx_msgs::msg::dds_::DetectedObject_" /-->
      </struct>
    </module>
    </module>
    </module>
    </types>



    <!-- Domain Library -->
    <domain_library name="MyDomainLibrary">
        <domain name="MyDomain" domain_id="0">
            <register_type name="openadx_msgs::msg::dds_::VehicleControl_"  type_ref="openadx_msgs::msg::dds_::VehicleControl_" />
            <topic name="control"    register_type_ref="openadx_msgs::msg::dds_::VehicleControl_"/>
            <register_type name="openadx_msgs::msg::dds_::DetectedObjectList_"  type_ref="openadx_msgs::msg::dds_::DetectedObjectList_" />
            <topic name="objects"    register_type_ref="openadx_msgs::msg::dds_::DetectedObjectList_"/>
        </domain>
    </domain_library>


    <!-- Participant library -->
    <domain_participant_library name="MyParticipantLibrary">
      <domain_participant name="Zero" domain_ref="MyDomainLibrary::MyDomain">

        <publisher name="MyPublisher">
          <data_writer name="VehicleObjectWriter" topic_ref="objects" />
        </publisher>
      
        <subscriber name="MySubscriber">
          <data_reader name="VehicleControlReader" topic_ref="control" />
        </subscriber>

        </domain_participant>
   </domain_participant_library>
</dds>
```

But my ROS2 node is not entering the callback function. Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299723/ros2-listener-not-entering-the-callback-function/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2018-08-06**:
Would you mind posting a full source file showing the issue? I suspect `rclpy.spin()` isn't being called, but I can't say for sure without seeing more of the code.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-06**:
@sloretz : I have updated the code

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
Have you tried publishing a dummy message using the command line tool `ros2 topic pub ...`? That should at least show you if the problem is in your subscriber or on the publisher side.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-06**:
Yes, I have tried that. Publishing from ROS2, I can subscribe on the native DDS Application.
I have also broken down the problem , publishing a simple string on the topic `chatter` and run the `listener.py` node in ROS2 but it still doesnt subscribe. Debugging it->doesnt enter callback. dont know y

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
If none of the tutorials work for you you might want to check if your network interface support multicasts.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-07**:
The machine on which I run native DDS does not support multicast but i guess this should not be a problem as the communication is working in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem.

RTI interprets unbounded string as `MAX_SIZE_INT32` which is `2147483647`. I had a variable in `header` as `string frame_id`. To establish communication between ROS2 and native DDS, the types should be same. So, in the QoS.xml, I gave the `maxStringLength = 2147483647`. This gave an error `create DataWriter buffer pool`. Refering to the RTI community, I created an extra `QoS setting for the data_writer and data_reader` :

```
    <datawriter_qos>
        <property>
            <value>
                <element>
                <name>dds.data_writer.history.memory_manager.fast_pool.pool_buffer_max_size</name>
                <value>2147483647</value>
                </element>
            </value>
        </property>
    </datawriter_qos>
    <datareader_qos>
        <property>
            <value>
                <element>
                <name>dds.data_writer.history.memory_manager.fast_pool.pool_buffer_max_size</name>
                <value>2147483647</value>
                </element>
            </value>
        </property>
    </datareader_qos>
```

This somehow lead to improper memory management and ROS2 wasnt able to subscribe any messages (not enterin the callback). I reduced the buffer size of the `datawriter to 2046` and now it works perfectly fine.

Question : Although I have found out the error, I am still not sure what are the possible reasons for it. Is it only memory creation problem ?

---

Originally posted by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) with karma: 667 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is you're not creating an instance of your DemoNode object at any point. If you look at [this subscriber example](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclpy/topics/minimal_subscriber/subscriber_member_function.py) you can see the structure you need.

Your main should look something like this:

```
def main(args=None):
    if args is None:
        args=sys.argv

    demo_node = DemoNode()
    rclpy.spin(demo_node)

    demo_node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-06**:
@PeterBlackerThe3rd...Thanks for noticing that. `I already had that in my code` but while typing the code manually in this post, I missed it by mistake. Sorry for the confusion.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-06**:
It might be another copy n paste  error but you're second to last line should be

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-06**:
You could put a couple of print statements in `main` and `DemoNode.__init__` to check they're being setup properly.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
The easiest would be to share the complete code of a package as well as the exact line of a publisher cli invocation. Than readers can try your case in literally a minute and comment if it is a problem in your code or not.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-07**:
Updated the entire code